# Cannot delegate event with jQuery Slides

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I've been trying to delegate event with jQuery Slides when new elements inside slider are created with no luck.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="slides">
    <div> 1 </div>
    <div> 2 </div>
    <div> 3 </div>
</div>
```

In JS I created a slider:

```
function init() {
    $('#slides').slidesjs({
    height: 100,
    navigation: {
        active: false
        },
        pagination: {
            active: false
        },
        play: {
            active: true,
            interval: 2000
        }
    });
}

init();
```

I'm trying to start slides on mouseover and stop on mouseleave, here's my code for that:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', "#slides", function() {
     console.log('mouseover');
     $(".slidesjs-play").trigger('click');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', "#slides", function() {
     console.log('mouseover');
     $(".slidesjs-stop").trigger('click');
});
```

It works fine but I need to do some filtering and add slider items dinamicaly, something like:

```
$("#redraw").on('click', function() {
    var slides = $('#slides').clone();
    $('#slides').empty();
    $('#slides').append(slides);
});
```

After this my slider doesn't work on mouseenter/mouseleave. I see events being triggered (`console.log()` works) but slider just won't start again.

What I've tried:

1. Add `init()` in mouseover
2. `$(this).find(".slidejs-play").trigger('click');`
3. Different plugins for slider (jquery cycles).

I believe it must be something small here however I could not grasp it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="slides">
    <div> 1 </div>
    <div> 2 </div>
    <div> 3 </div>
</div>

<button id="redraw">  Redraw </button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

    $(document).on('mouseover', "#slides", function() {
         console.log('mouseover');
         $(".slidesjs-play").trigger('click');
    });

    $(document).on('mouseleave', "#slides", function() {
         console.log('mouseover');
         $(".slidesjs-stop").trigger('click');
    });

    $("#redraw").on('click', function() {
        var slides = $('#slides').clone();
        $('#slides').empty();
        $('#slides').append(slides);
    });

    function init() {
        $('#slides').slidesjs({
        height: 100,
        navigation: {
            active: false
            },
            pagination: {
                active: false
            },
            play: {
                active: true,
                interval: 2000
            }
        });

    }

    init();

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5meb/11/)

Comment: I never heard of `slideJS`, but most probably if you change the slides you have to init the slideshow again, or call some sort of update function.

Comment: I've tried adding init() in "mouseover" event and in redraw function but that didn't help.

Comment: `var slides = $('#slides').clone(true);` -  Copy handler along with the elements.

Comment: Next time when you add JSFiddle, always include full code in question too.

Comment: @DavidDomain that works, thank you! Didn't know you could pass anything inside clone.

Comment: And when you do this `var slides = $('#slides').clone();
        $('#slides').empty();
        $('#slides').append(slides);` you always add more `div`s with the `slides` ID. What exactly are you trying to do here? This is a **HUGE** memory leak.